# Is 'ponder' acceptable as a quotative verb, for instance with inner dialogue?

Tags: word-usage, quoting

There has been a question on ELU about the acceptability of transitive **ponder** (ponder an issue) versus ponder about (etc) an issue. This question asks rather about the acceptability of *ponder* in an (especially inner-dialogue) quotative verb role, obviously retaining the usual sense of 'consider deeply and carefully, ruminate'):

- *Was she coming*? he wondered.
- ?*And just what pleasure have I found, since I came into this world*? he pondered.

I haven't found a single relevant sentence supporting this usage among the many examples given at [TheCambridgeDictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ponder), [Merriam-Webster](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ponder), [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ponder), [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/collocations/british/ponder#ponder__1), and [CollinsCobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ponder), nor any at AHD or Wiktionary. And I'm finding it difficult to restrict searches to the quotative usage.

Collins CoBuild: Verbs: Grammar Patterns 1: Simple Patterns ... Section 13 {Verb with Quote} lists only 3 quotative verbs in the 'think' semantic group: *muse think wonder*.

However, I just used *he pondered* as an emphatic version of *he asked himself* almost without thinking (almost ... hence this question), and I've managed to track down the following recent example of what is probably a central (verbal) quotative usage:

> ... But Walter Shapiro last month reported Biden's complaints against
> the oft-expressed intention of the ultra-liberal netroots to 'take
> back' the party. "They don't own the Democratic Party. What are they
> talking about?" he pondered.

[[Niall Stanage; the Guardian; 2020 but reference to 2008 article](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2007/aug/13/gojoebiden)]

I can't see how the opposite can really be proved, but are there better supporting references licensing the quotative usage?

Comment: If I understand your point here, it seems to turn on the idea that we can interpret *[Question] **he pondered*** as a "transitive" usage, as we would with, say, ***He asked** [question]*. If that's right, how about the many instances of the construction *[Question] [**he mused***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22why+he+mused%22) in Google Books - even though no-one ever uses the construction ***He mused** [question]*.

Comment: (Or are you just looking for examples featuring the sequence [*"why he pondered"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22why+he+pondered%22)?)

Comment: I see quote structures (quote plus speech tag) as different from transitive or intransitive usages, and certainly the acceptability of 'He pondered for several minutes', 'He pondered the question', and 'He pondered about this' do not guarantee the acceptability of 'He pondered "Why do these things always happen to me?" '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see in this matter nothing else but a question of semantics. In the [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/wonder_1?q=wonder) this particular type of  construction is regularly labelled as "[V-speech]" (in the online edition "+speech"), meaning "verb followed by speech"; this classification departs from the traditional transitive/intransitive scheme as those uses ([V-speech]) are found to be neither. A different semantical context must be supported grammatically by a different grammatical category.

*The examples that can be found in this dictionary*
(those I could remember or glean in the various remarks on the present ELU page, which might be sufficient for the purpose of drawing conclusions)

*A - First kind*

**say** [V-speech] ('*Hello!' She said*) ♦ **tell** [VN-speech] (*'I'm ready to go now,' he told her.*) ♦  **go** (infml) [V-speech] (*I asked 'How much?' and he goes 'Fifty' and I go 'Fifty? You must be joking!'*) ♦ **continue**  [V-speech] (*'In fact,' he continued, 'I'd like to congratulate you.'*) ♦ **add** [V-speech] (*'And don't be late,' he added.*) ♦ **bark** ♦ **yell** [V-speech] (*'Be careful!' he yelled.*) ♦ **repeat** [V-speech] (*'Are you sure?, she repeated.*) ♦ **interject** [V-speech] (*'You're wrong,' interjected Suzan.*) ♦ **smile** [V-speech] ♦ **laugh** [V-speech] (*'You're crazy! she laughed.*) ♦ **beam** [V-speech] ♦ **grumble** ♦ **exclaim** ♦ **pant** ♦ **retort**, ♦ **breathe** ♦   **think** [V-speech] ('*I must be crazy,' she thought.*)♦ **muse** (syn. *ponder*) [V-speech] …

*B - Second kind*

**ask** [V-speech] (*'Where are you going ?' she asked.*) ♦ **complain** [V-speech] (*'It is not fair,' she complained.*) ♦ **exhort** [V-speech][VN-speech] ♦ **advise** [V-speech][VN-speech] ♦ **warn** [V-speech][VN-speech] ♦ **promise** [V-speech][VN-speech] ♦ **order** [V-speech][VN-speech] ♦ **answer** [V-speech][VN-speech] ♦ **request** [V-speech] ♦ **wonder** [V-speech] (*'What should I do now?' she wondered.*) ♦ [**ponder**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/ponder?q=ponder) [V-speech] (‘I wonder why,’ she pondered aloud.) …

It is clear, from the end of this list that the usage has been recognized; however, this is not the answer in my opinion.

It is clear that for the verbs of the first kind, the action is that of the reporting of an occurrence of  an enunciation or, in addition to that, the manner in which this enunciation is carried out.
In the second kind there is not any more in the meaning  of the verbs a concern with reporting an enunciation; this is taken for granted: in all cases the verb can be replaced by any of the verbs of the first kind (bar for an adjustment: told *them/him,…*)) and the sentence remains meaningful. It is not so if we look at this the other way around.
All that can be made out in the meaning of the verbs of the latter kind is a concern with the sort of quoted speech; they characterize *semantically* the *type of enunciation* that this quoted speech constitutes.

*From [Wikipedia, speech act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_act)*

> In the philosophy of language and linguistics, speech act is something expressed by an individual that not only presents information, but performs an action as well.
> Speech acts serve their function once they are said or communicated. These are commonly taken to include acts such as *apologizing, promising, ordering, answering, requesting, complaining, warning, inviting, refusing, and congratulating*.

*Note that all the verbs in the second kind are in one of those categories and that in the above dictionary only for four of the categories the  corresponding  verb  is not "V-speech" or "VN-speech (apologizing, inviting, refusing, and congratulating)*. One may wonder why, as for instance the following possibilities appear justified.

- 'Sorry for that,' apologized Irene. (*There is in fact an example in [this book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=W0HXAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT89&dq=%22apologized%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj01bnenMXsAhXUDmMBHQ6tDBAQ6AEwSXoECA4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22apologized%22&f=false): House of Gold, Bud Macfarlane 2014.*)
- 'Get in,' invited Irene. (*likely enough possibility*)
- 'A blunt "No",' refused Irene. (*less likely than the preceding but not unconceivable*)
- 'Well done,' Irene congratulated him. (*One instance is found in [this book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=uSorXtyfYrcC&pg=PT589&dq=%22congratulated%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiL1Kz6o8XsAhVL8OAKHQ9oDnw4ZBDoATBJegQIEhAC#v=onepage&q=%22congratulated%22&f=false): Sword of the Gods: The Chosen One: (Book 1 of the Sword of ... Anna Erishkigal  2012.*)

All verbs of the second kind are of the nature of verbs that can be used for a speech act. They are all performative verbs except "wonder". ("Ponder" is not a performative either.)

*From Wikipedia, [Performative verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_verb)*

> Performative verbs are verbs [the action of which is] carried out simply by means of uttering them aloud. When a judge sentences someone to jail time, for example, the action is completed when he or she says, "I hereby sentence you to five years in prison," or the like.
>
> One can identify a performative verb by using the "Hereby" Test. In English, only performative verbs may be preceded by "hereby" while other verbs in the same context are unacceptable.

- <s>I hereby wonder what you should do.</s>
- <s>I hereby ponder  what pleasures I have found.</s>
- <s>I hereby think that I must be crazy.</s>
- <s>I hereby muse that.</s>

*From [ThoughtCo, Performative verbs](https://www.thoughtco.com/performative-verb-1691606)*

> In English grammar and speech-act theory, a performative verb is a verb **that explicitly conveys the type of speech act being performed**. A speech act is an expression of intent—therefore, a performative verb, also called a speech-act verb or performative utterance, is an action that conveys intent. A speech act can be in the form of a promise, invitation, apology, prediction, vow, request, warning, insistence, forbiddance, and more. Verbs accomplishing any of these are performative verbs.

The nature of the quoted speech construction for verbs that do not correspond to a simple reporting of  a speech occurrence, because they have a meaning totally foreign to that effect, must be taken as formulating an idea related to the meaning of the quoted utterance. Otherwise, what is their role in the quoted speech construction? There is no connection. The pattern imposes on the verb the necessity of being performative: the action is executed entirely while the speech act lasts.

*The nature of the quoted speech*

- 'X,' she asked: X a request. ♦ 'X,' she complained: X is a complaint. ♦ 'X,' he exhorted: X is an exhortation. ♦ 'X,' he  warned: X is a warning. ♦ 'X,' he  promises: X is  a promise. ♦ 'X,' he ordered: X is an order. ♦ 'X,' he answered: X is an answer.
- 'X,' she  wondered: is X a spell of wondering? No, it is the subject of it, the wondering is not explicited in X as it is *about* X. Can this spell be considered to be confined to the time of the speech act? Hardly so; "wonder", on the basis of its definition is a dynamic verb ([to think about sth and decide](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/wonder_1?q=wonder)) but it seems to be perceived ambiguously as it is considered to be a stative verb, also as it is considered to be used in the progressive only exceptionally.

*"The uttering of a performative is, or is part of, the doing of a certain kind of action.* ([Performative utterance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_utterance))
"
It follows that all performative verbs are first of all dynamic.

"Ponder", while it is a dynamic verb,  is not performative: it does not characterize the quoted speech as an act of pondering and suffers from the same defect "wonder" does. Moreover, pondering is not the type of action that can be carried out in the quasi timeless span of such a short utterance, whether on the level of an inner dialogue or otherwise.
As to "muse" and "think", the same goes for them unless they can be taken as  connoting a manner of saying (saying in a contemplative mood, saying silently something to oneself), and they are then verbs that fits in the first kind;  the definitions in OALD does  support this possibility in the case of "[muse (2)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/muse_2)"; it is not quite so for "[think (3)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/think_1?q=think)" as its definition makes of it a stative verb; nevertheless I did put it in the first class.

As I plowed through the literature I couldn't pinpoint  any reference to the effect of this specific licensing, but I believe that the evidence gathered tends greatly towards the non-licensing, although in a deductive manner.

Comment: The OALD licensing answers my question, but there's a lot of interesting discussion here too. I've accepted the 'this classification departs from the traditional transitive/intransitive scheme as those uses ([V-speech]) are found to be neither' stance for years, but not seen it spelled out, merely mentioned as an approach favoured by some grammarians.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not better informed on that approach still new to me and I wonder how the idea of object can be refuted in all cases.

Comment: Easy. Just choose your definition. And don't totally divorce semantics / pragmatics from your approach to grammar. Accept that << He saw mum >> and  << He said "Mum" >> should be seen as distinct constructions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That is something I turned over in my head often, starting with the premise that—since the nomenclature is changed—a new relation has been found relevant; but I am not even sure of what element I should speak: is it 'mum' or is it '"mum"'?

Answer (score 0):

> However, I just used he pondered as an emphatic version of he asked himself almost without thinking.

This is either an incorrect description of what he was doing, or a misunderstanding of "to ponder".

> This question asks rather about the acceptability of ponder in an (especially inner-dialogue) quotative verb role, obviously retaining the usual sense of 'consider deeply and carefully, ruminate'):
>
> I haven't found a single relevant sentence supporting this usage among the many examples

Here are a few from the OED:

> **Ponder**
>
> **3. a.** *transitive.* **To weigh (a matter, words, etc.) mentally, esp. before making a decision or reaching a conclusion; to think over, consider, or reflect on; to wonder about. Frequently with clause as object.**
>
> 1760   L. Sterne Life Tristram Shandy I. xx. 131   *Then, Madam, be pleased to ponder well the last line but one of the chapter.*

> 1799   Reginald III. xi. 286   *I pondered whether I ought not to return.*

> 2000   L. M. McTaggart Being Catholic Today xvii. 142   *Read that extract again, and ponder its implications.*

and

> **4.** *intransitive.* **To think or reflect deeply, to meditate; to contemplate, to muse; to wonder. Frequently with on, upon, over, about.**
>
> a1593   C. Marlowe Tragicall Hist. Faustus (1604) sig. E4v   *Leave me a while to ponder on my sinnes.*
>
> 1881   W. Besant & J. Rice Chaplain of Fleet I. i. 10   *A message from the dead, to keep and ponder over?*
>
> 1991   New Scientist 30 Nov. 49/3   *Essential reading for anyone left pondering about the relationship between a buff-bellied pipit and a Pechora pipit.*

Comment: But does OED sanction such often novel usages as She smiled “I don’t believe you” 
[An historical syntax of the English language; Vol 1 part 3; F T Visser] and quotative usages of _speculate_, _beam_, _estimate_ (Collins Cobuild) etc? I've pre-empted the "I can't find any in a dictionary" response, said how difficult filtered searches are, mentioned lots of interference-examples, and I've added one relevant example.