# Should I use a period or comma in the dialogue preceding "nodded" or "gestured"?

Tags: punctuation, commas, periods, dialogue

Not the first time the question appears. I was wondering about usage of commas and periods in dialogues. Here’s an example from the recent book I chanced upon:

> “The tea,” she gestured. “Snakes are poisonous, you know.”
>
> “Oh,” Argrave nodded, enlightened. He was content to stay silent, let her think him incautious. As something came to mind, he asked curiously, “Do you actually have any poison on hand? Potent poison.”

From what I know, *gestured* and *nodded* are to be considered action tags. So should there be a period in both of these cases? Is this a mistake and should it be gotten rid off? Or is it not something to fuss about?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to find a novel published by a major agency and look at it. gestured and nodded make the writing more lively.  You can actually see the usage: "Dialogue blah blah blah," subject pronoun + verb. I never heard the term action tag. They just characterize what a character is saying.

Comment: See here for "action tag" https://www.writingbeginner.com/how-to-use-action-tags-in-dialogue/  I had also not heard of it, but then I never formally studied writing dialog.  There was the "swiftie" type of joke when I was young.

Comment: *Infinite Jest,* by David Foster Wallace, has an extended brilliant dialogue, pp. 242-58. You can learn from him.

Comment: Full stops are used because the following speech is a new sentence.

Comment: The use of novel quotative verbs (verbs used in quote structures as part of a dialogue tag; contrast true report/ing verbs) is widely accepted, especially in the writing of novels, where the novel (oops) verb adds meaning. 'He nodded / gestured / brayed / squeaked ...'.  Punctuate as you would if the quotative verb were the prototypical _say/says/said_. // Although the colon and zero punctuation are often available and sometimes preferable, I'd say the comma is by far the best option here.

Comment: Do [Is _ponder_ acceptable as a quotative verb ...?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/549668/is-ponder-acceptable-as-a-quotative-verb-for-instance-with-inner-dialogue), [history of _smile one's thanks_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227685/history-of-smile-ones-thanks/227702#227702), [word for explaining ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/579222/word-for-explaining-something-cruelly/579232#579232) or [he nodded his head 'yes'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133778/he-nodded-his-head-yes-she-shook-her-head-no/165866#165866) help, Alexander?

Answer (score 0):

You would use a period for a dialogue line before an action tag. The comma after a line of dialogue indicates that we're going to get more information on the spoken line.

"The tea," she gestured - implies that she somehow gestured the dialogue (perhaps with sign language). Correct usage would be either:

"The tea." She gestured. (action tag)

or

"The tea," she said. (Speaker tag rather than action tag)

Note that this is a stylistic preference that's currently accepted - some authors can get away with violating this, but for maximum clarity I would stick with this guideline.

See this quote:

"Don’t punctuate the preceding dialogue with a comma. Unless the action beat interrupts a dialogue sentence (see example above), always end the dialogue preceding the action beat as you would if it stood alone."

Per this site:
https://www.helpingwritersbecomeauthors.com/most-common-mistakes-series-how-not-to/

Comment: Hello, Mo. I'm afraid I can't see where the linked site refers to the semantically charged quotative verbs often considered acceptable in such sentences as << "Don't forget to try the home-made jam," Mary smiled. >> This is different to say << "Don't forget to try the home-made jam" – Mary smiled. >> I'd say they differ in meaning also: the first demands synchronicity, while the second at least hints strongly at sequentiality.